# How can I sync my nodeos with a Mainnet or Testnet?

Tags: nodeos, testnet, mainnet, blockchains

I can't find in the [wiki](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki) how do you sync your nodeos with a testnet or mainnet. I need this for a project I'm developing.

Comment: I found a [very detailed answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/726/360) to sync nodeos to the mainnet in order to vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each network has a `genesis.json` file. Start `nodeos` with that file and with `--p2p-peer-address` set to 1 or more nodes on that network.