# How to vote using cleos?

Tags: voting, cleos

Currently there are some voting portals and tools like:

- [EOS Portal and Scatter](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8pz8or/how_to_vote_for_bps_using_scatter_video_tutorial/) (use it only via https!)
- [eosc](https://github.com/eoscanada/eosc)
- [eos-voter](https://github.com/greymass/eos-voter)
- [tokenika](https://steemit.com/eos/@tokenika/off-line-voting-tool-for-eos-block-production)

I think currently the only official and secure way to vote is to use [cleos](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/cleos-overview).
I have configured local node with Docker and can use cleos locally as described here - [Docker Quickstart - cleos](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart#section-cleos)

My questions are:

- How can I configure cleos to talk to the main net?
- How can I vote using cleos?

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

I also found nice article here - [EOS Block Producer Voting Using the Command Line](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/your-vote-matters-3-eos-block-producer-voting-using-the-command-line)
It is using Docker and actually all the interaction is happening inside the container.
We just need HTTP/API endpoint of the official block producer (for example, you can use https://mainnet.eoscanada.com as a **--url** parameter when working with **cleos** and **mainnet**)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Warning, this is probably wayyy outdated, feel free to make change requests :)

---

Credit Chris from Privex (@chr54 Telegram) >>
 **Producer Name** ***privexinceos***

**How to Vote Via Command Line (cleos):**

[Want the Docker Version?](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/your-vote-matters-3-eos-block-producer-voting-using-the-command-line)

---

This tutorial assumes you have at least one registered EOS public/private key pair and EOS tokens to stake for the purposes of voting.

1. Install/Build EOS (build script changes SYS namespace token to EOS)

   - `git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos --recursive`
   - `cd eos`
   - `./eosio_build.sh -s "EOS"`
   - `cd build`
   - `sudo make install`

**If you don't want to run a node, skip to step 8.  Running a node is not necessary to vote.**

2. Create genesis.json file using genesis data:

   - https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/eos/blob/launch-rc-1.0.2/mainnet-genesis.json
   - `sudo nano ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/genesis.json`
   - Copy, Paste, and Save.
3. Run `nodeos --print-default-config` once to produce initital config.ini file

   - To edit `sudo nano ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini`
4. Add p2p nodes to config.ini (from site https://eosnodes.privex.io/?config=1)

   - Search for `p2p-peer-address =`
5. Add plugins to config.ini

   `plugin = eosio::producer_plugin 
   plugin = eosio::wallet_api_plugin 
   plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin 
   plugin = eosio::http_plugin 
   plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin`

   - Search `plugin =`
6. Change localhost port so it doesn't overlap with keosd in config.ini

   - Search `http-server-address =`
   - Change port to 8080
7. Run `nodeos --delete-all-blocks --genesis-json` (from gensis.json directory)

   - On subsequent launches, do not specify `--genesis-json`, nodeos will pull the genesis state from the block log, and of course do not `--delete-all-blocks` either.
   - If nodeos does not restart cleanly, `--replay-blockchain` and if that does not work `--hard-replay-blockchain`.

---

8. In separate terminal, start keosd with `keosd`
9. Create a wallet

   - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888/ wallet create`
   - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-wallet-create
10. Save wallet password (**very important**) and import private key to wallet

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888/ wallet import PRIVATE_KEY`
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-wallet-import
11. Figure out a full node to connect to and run get info (known full nodes below)

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] get info`
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-info
12. Get account info on your account

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] get account eosuseraaaaa`
    - If you don’t know what your account name is, please type your public key into EOS Authority’s tool which will provide it https://eosauthority.com/
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-accounts
13. Delegate EOS tokens to perform voting

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] system delegatebw eosuseraaaaa "0.1000 EOS" "0.1000 EOS"`
    - Positional Args `from TEXT - The account delegating bandwidth
      receiver TEXT - The account to delegate bandwidth from 
      stake_net_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to delegate for network bandwidth stake_cpu_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to delegate for CPU bandwidth`
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-delegatebw
14. List producers to vote on

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] system listproducers`
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-listproducers
15. Vote on producers by including their names in the following command

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] system voteproducer prods eosuseraaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa2 aaaaaaaaaaa4`
    - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-voteproducer-prods
    - Note that up to 30 producers may be voted on equally based on your stake
16. List Producers again to see how your vote affected the producers %

    - `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888 --url http://[NODE_IP_HERE]:[NODE_PORT_HERE] system listproducers`

---

FAQ:

1. Where can I find more detailed cleos commands?

   - Either type -h after your command or go to: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/cleos-overview
2. I voted, what else should I do

   - Create another account since yours is just a bunch of random letters and cannot be changed
   - New account must be 12 characters in length
   - `cleos system newaccount --stake-net "0.1000 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1000 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 8 <youraccount> <newaccount> <ownerpublickey> <activepublickey>`
   - if you want to transfer, use with `--transfer`
   - be aware that you have to **purchase** RAM to do this. 8kb ram is around 0.12 EOS
3. I'm not a programmer, so I'm not comfortable voting this way, is there another way you would recommend?

   - Nathan James is a trusted member of the community and developed the Scatter Wallet
   - https://get-scatter.com - wallet
   - https://bloks.io - site to vote on

---

Known nodes:

https://get-scatter.com/

`cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get info`

`cleos -u http://nodes.get-scatter.com:80 get info`

load balances over multiple BP endpoints 
**courtesy of nsjames**

https://eos.cafe/

`cleos -u http://mainnet.eoscalgary.io:80 get info`

http://eosdetroit.io/

`cleos -u https://api.eosdetroit.io:443 get info`

https://www.eosnewyork.io/

`cleos -v -u http://api.eosnewyork.io get info`

https://www.eosphere.io/

`cleos -u https://node1.eosphere.io get info`

`cleos -u https://node2.eosphere.io get info`

https://www.saltblock.io/home

`cleos -u https://eos.saltblock.io get info`

---

List of nodes to try:

1. https://eosnodes.privex.io/
2. https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79276/discussion-on-answer-by-nat-how-to-vote-using-cleos).